# How can I get clap to wrap long help messages?

Tags: rust

Here is an example:

```
extern crate clap;
use clap::{Arg, App};

fn main() {
let args = App::new("test")
    .arg(Arg::with_name("scoring_method")
            .short("s")
            .long("scoring-method")
            .help("Very very very very very very long long long long long help help help help help message message message message message message message"))
    .get_matches();
}
```

Leads to the help text formatting like this:

[image: console example]

(pasting in code mode causes Stack Overflow to fix the formatting issue)

The exact string produced is:

```
'USAGE:\n    play [FLAGS]\n\nFLAGS:\n    -h, --help              Prints help information\n    -s, --scoring-method    Very very very very very very long long long long long help help help help help message\n                            message message message message message message\n    -V, --version           Prints version information'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clap has a [max_term_width](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#method.max_term_width) that it uses to wrap the text that it outputs. As mentioned in that documentation, it defaults to `120` characters, which is why you see the text split *eventually*, but not where you'd hoped.

If you have a certain width that you'd like to set, you can use [set_term_width](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#method.set_term_width) with a specific value. Alternatively, you can use a crate like [terminal_size](https://github.com/eminence/terminal-size) to get the size of the current terminal, and use that to set the width for `clap` to use.

As a full example:

```
extern crate clap;
extern crate terminal_size;

use clap::{App, Arg};
use terminal_size::{terminal_size, Width};

fn main() {
    let args = App::new("test")
    .set_term_width(if let Some((Width(w), _)) = terminal_size() { w as usize } else { 120 })
    .arg(Arg::with_name("scoring_method")
      .short("s")
      .long("scoring-method")
      .help("Very very very very very very long long long long long help help help help help message message message message message message message"))
    .get_matches();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Today (Clap v4.0.26) you can enable the `wrap_help` feature. This takes a dependency on `terminal_size` internally.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, `clap` auto-magically does wrap the help text output within the terminal width if the `wrap_help` feature is enabled as shown with the following snippet of `Cargo.toml`:

```
clap = {version = "4.0.18", features=["derive","wrap_help"]}
```